# Using switch case in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, switch-statement

Am I writing this code correctly?

```
var dropdownOptions;
var value;
function randomNumberGenerator(max, min) {
    var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
    return randomNumber;
}

function nonLive(dropdown,max,min) {  //Genereal function    
    dropdownOptions = $(dropdown).children('option');
    //value = randomNumberGenerator(max,min); //randomizing number
    switch(randomNumberGenerator(max,min)) {
        case 1 :   
            $('select option:eq(1)').attr("selected", true);
        case 2:    
            $('select option:eq(2)').attr("selected", true);
    }
    //return dropdownOptions.attr('selected', false).eq(value).attr('selected', true).change();
}

function live(dropdown,max,min) {
    nonLive(dropdown,max,min);
    return dropdownOptions.attr('selected', false).eq(value).attr('selected', true).change();
}

function call() {
    $("#child1,#child2").each(function () {
        live($(this),1,1);
    });
}

call();
```

I want to switch between parameters 1 and 2. If for example I pass, `live($(this),1,1)` it should **always** select the first option of my drop down. If I pass something like `live($(this),2,2)` it should select any random option except the first option. I know that giving two parameters is not efficient. So, please feel free to optimize.

Comment: Is it compulsion to use switch i thing if else will make code easier

Comment: @mean: My first choice was to try with if-else. But I can't seem to make it work. Would be great if you could help me with either the switch case or the if-else. Thanks.

Comment: share fiddle please

Comment: after case please use break;

Comment: @mean: https://jsfiddle.net/mvwk0nue/

Comment: @mean: Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mvwk0nue/1/

Comment: Anybody who can help me with this?